# map is not a function on array React

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an error that map is not a function on my data.
I'm getting a response back from an api that is returning an array of objects. When I don't refresh the page I can view the results displayed just fine and even navigate to view them individually (when I click on see more). However, when I refresh the page I get the
error of "Map is not a function" on my props even though the results are displaying in the console log.

I'm lost here and can't figure out why it's doing that.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCanyons();
    }

render() {
        const { canyons } = this.props;
        console.log(canyons)
        return (
            <section>
                
                {canyons.map(canyon => (
                    <section key={canyon.canyon_id}>
                        <h3>{canyon.canyon_name}</h3>
                        <img src={canyon.canyon_pic} alt={canyon.canyon_name} />
                        <Link key={canyon.canyon_id} to={`/canyon/${canyon.canyon_id}`}>
                            <button>See More</button>
                        </Link>
                    </section>
                ))}
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the api failed or having lag time to get response, it may be `undefined`. This kind of checking prevent you to from such problem.

```
return (  
    {canyons && canyons.map(canyon => (
     ...skipped code
    ))}
)
```

Typescript provide feature of adding a `?` before try to access the related `Object` type variable

```
//In typescript
{canyons?.map(canyon => (
     ...skipped code
))}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked for me.  I have an async /await on the query it's fetching so not sure why it would lag. Regardless thought it's working now.  Thank you!

Comment: @User1990 React won't wait for the query to resolve before rendering the component just because the function itself is asynchronous. There will be some time between your component mounting and the server response completing where your component will be in an intermediate state of having no data but still being displayed. You need to account for that by adding a loading state of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

```js
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCanyons();
    }

render() {
        const { canyons } = this.props;
        console.log(canyons)
        return (
            <section>
                
                {   canyons !== '' || canyons.length > 0 ? //change here
                    canyons.map(canyon => (
                    <section key={canyon.canyon_id}>
                        <h3>{canyon.canyon_name}</h3>
                        <img src={canyon.canyon_pic} alt={canyon.canyon_name} />
                        <Link key={canyon.canyon_id} to={`/canyon/${canyon.canyon_id}`}>
                            <button>See More</button>
                        </Link>
                    </section>
                ))
                :
                null
                }
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

Please follow the change. It should works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers provide a live view when using console.log(). When the request not finished 'canyons' is undefined. Use

```
 console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))
```

For this problem, try to set default value or check variable first